# Collection.upsert() vs Collection.update() with "upsert: true"

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using MongoDB in Meteor. I found that to update(*if already exist*) the data or insert in collection [`update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) can be used with [`upsert: true`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-upsert). There's also a method called [`upsert()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/) which can also be used to update/insert a record.

**Code:**<sup>(From Meteor)</sup>

Using `update`:

```
Collection.update({
    _id: id
}, {
    $set: {
        content: 'SomeText'
    }
}, {
    upsert: true
});
```

Using `upsert`:

```
Collection.upsert({
    _id: id
}, {
    $set: {
        content: 'SomeText'
    }
});
```

**Question:**

1. **Difference:** What is the difference between `update()` with `upsert` flag set to `true` and `upsert()`
2. **Use Case:** When should use the `update()` or `upsert()`

Comment: Hi @Tushar. Pls get into http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142900/room-for-avi-and-tushar if you're free.. :--)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the mongo code from meteor source (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo/collection.js#L640)

```
Mongo.Collection.prototype.upsert = function upsert(
    selector, modifier, options, callback) {
  if (! callback && typeof options === "function") {
    callback = options;
    options = {};
  }

  const updateOptions = _.extend({}, options, {
    _returnObject: true,
    upsert: true
  });

  return this.update(selector, modifier, updateOptions, callback);
};
```

So `upsert` just a short hand for `update` with option `upsert` set to `true`.
There is no different you can use whatever function you like

Comment: So, `upsert` is of Meteor's layer on `update`. What if I passed `upsert: false` to `upsert()` will it work

Comment: yes even if you pass `upsert: false` to `upsert()` it will be overridden by  `_.extend` as `{_returnObject: true, upsert: true }` is the last source (http://underscorejs.org/#extend)

Answer (score -3):

the latter upsert is a component of the javascript shell [bulk operation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk). im sure its not exposed by any driver to date.

Comment: In Meteor, it is allowed to use on Collection.